# Remove (bool)false values from array in flash

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have an array that has a lot of values including a lot of 'false' values.
Is there any way of removing the 'false' values that is faster than this:

```
function removeFalseValues (arr:Array):Array {
    var ret:Array = new Array ();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        if (arr[i]) ret.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [`filter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter%28%29).

For example:

```
arr = arr.filter( function(item:*):Boolean { 
    return item; 
});
```

Note that this example, like the code you posted will also filter other items such as `0`, `null` objects and empty strings.

If you want to keep these values, you can change the previous code into:

```
arr = arr.filter( function(item:*):Boolean { 
    return item || !(item is Boolean); 
});
```

Comment: `arr = arr.filter(function (e):Boolean {return Boolean(e);});` ?